# Terminology for mobile computing with a tablet?

Tags: terminology, smartclient, tablet, medical, occasionallyconnected

This is more of a terminology question...

I'm developing an occasionally connected application that will run on a tablet for clinicians or field service workers but I'm struggling with what this type of computing is referred to.  Mobile computing as connotations of a phone app.  Whereas our clients may be occasionally at their desk.  Microsoft uses Smart Client a lot, but I'm not sure if that best describes this scenario or is the common term for this kind of computing.

Answer (score 1):

In healthcare, it's called "Point of Care" or POC, e.g. using a POC device or application while taking care of a patient.

Answer (score 0):

Is **Tablet Computing** a bit too blunt for you? It's certainly a well-known term, and it seems to adequately describe your client's use case.

Comment: Thank you; That's not bad but it could lead people to think that it's just a tablet solution.  I'm looking for a term that would also represent a trucker with a laptop in his cab or a social worker carrying a laptop while she's making visits or a tablet that's carried around a warehouse etc.